# Codeigniter newbie: Count query results?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have my query:

```
$query = $this->db
        ->get_where('users', array('group_id' => 7, 'active' => 1));
```

It works if I use:

```
print_r ($query->result());
```

All I want to do, is get the total number of rows that match my query. I've tried num_rows and count(), but I can't get either of them to work!

Any help would be greatly appreciated! At the moment, I am just testing this in my view, but will move it over to my model when I figure it out.

Thanks!!

Comment: try `sizeof($query->result())`

Comment: Try `count($query->result())`

Comment: $query->num_rows() as stated in the documentation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `$query->num_rows()`. It will return total number of rows returned using your query.

for example :

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
       //DO your stuff
    }
```

For more reference see [Documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html).

Comment: Thank you. I had tried playing around with num_rows, but couldn't get it!! I have it now though :)

Answer (score 0):

Try [count_all_results](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Example:

```
echo $this->db->count_all_results('my_table');
// Produces an integer, like 25

$this->db->like('title', 'match');
$this->db->from('my_table');
echo $this->db->count_all_results();
// Produces an integer, like 17
```

OR

```
echo $this->db->where('group_id',1)->count_all_results('users');
```